# pandas different column names same data

Tags: pandas

How do i use the same data storage and change only the columns.

If i do something like this:

```
In [30]: import pandas as pd

In [31]: import numpy as np

In [32]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2,2)))

In [33]: df_new = pd.DataFrame(df)

In [34]: df[0][0]=5

In [35]: df_new
Out[35]:
     0    1
0  5.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0

In [36]: df_new.columns=["a", "b"]
In [37]: df_new.columns
Out[37]: Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')

In [38]: df.columns
Out[38]: Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

Changes columns for both dataframes. Using dataframe `rename` inplace leads to columns being changed for both dataframes.

Comment: To clarify, I want to use the same data storage. so that changes to df_new reflect in df. I only want the column names to be different

Comment: Is it because of the storage constraints or you just want to propagate the changes from `df_new` to `df` as they happen?

Comment: memory constraints. Don't want to copy data . But I am using `sklearn_pandas` that barfs up on integer column names. So I need to convert them to strings but I don't want to affect the input dataframe

Comment: In that case, how about having a `dict` which has a key value pair of `int` and `string` column names. It will be a separate mapping with your `df` to call the columns in whatever manner you want to call.

Comment: This is the problem:
I have to write function `take_df` that takes dataframe from user and i have to call a package called `sklearn_pandas` that I do now own a dataframe. `sklearn_pandas` would only work with string column names. So I can't realy use your solution.

Comment: Ofcourse my function does a bunch of other things too.

Comment: Use `df.columns.map(str)` to convert your `df.columns` from `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)` to `Index(['0', '1'], dtype='object')`. Now `0` and `1` will be column labels in string format.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pandas.DataFrame.copy()` to create a copy of an existing dataframe.

For your code,

```
df_new = df.copy()
```

instead of

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: To clarify, I want to use the same data storage. so that changes to `df_new` reflect in `df`. I only want the column names to be different.